# Run the some code whenever I upload the project on to the app engine server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appserver

I've built an appeninge project so, how can I run some piece of code on the appserver only once, i.e  when ever I upload the whole project on to the server.

How should I achieve this task???

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official way to discover if your application has been modified altought each time you upload your application it gets a unique version number {app version.(some unique number)} but since there isn't a document API on how to get it I wound't take a risk and use it.

What you need todo is to have a script that will upload your application and when the script is done you can call a handler in your application that set a value in the datastore that marks the application as new.
Once you have that, you can look for it in the datastore in your handlers and run the code if you find it.

Comment: Thank u very much,
I don't know how to write handler for app enigne code can u give me the documentions or example

Comment: @user578542 If you don't know how to write a handler in App Engine, you don't know how to write an App Engine app at all, and you should start with the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/).

Comment: @NickJohnson Thanks for ur suggestion i will start today.